# Ring theory question please?Simple.

Tags: ring-theory

We have the Cartesian product $B \times B$ and there we have the addition
$$(f,g)+(h,k)=(f+h,g+k)$$
and the multiplication
$$(f,g) \cdot (h,k)=(f\cdot h+g\cdot k,f\cdot k+g\cdot h).$$
I want to find the identity element of the group related to the addition. So I must have something like $(f,g)+e=(f,g)$. What do I do now? Is it something like ($f+e,g)=(f,g)$?

Answer (score 1):

Of course $e$ is also a pair, $e=(e_1,e_2)$. What can you conclude from $(f,g)+(e_1,e_2)=(f,g)$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $B$ is a group, it has an identity element $e$. In $B \times B$, therefore
$$
(f,g) + (e,e) = (f + e, g + e) = (f,g)
$$
for any elements $f$ and $g$, so $(e,e)$ is the identity in $B \times B$.

Comment: this means that e=0 right?

Comment: You don't determine what $e$ is. $e$ is supposed to be the identity element of $B$ with respect to addition. By this calculation $(e,e)$ is the identity in $B \times B$.

Comment: @Youmath If by "$0$" you mean "the identity element of $B$ with respect to addition", then yes. You want to be careful with that terminology, however. The group $B$ could be strange and not have an element called "$0$". It might not have any numbers at all.